# Error when accessing anything but default route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, mono

I am having trouble getting routing to work on mono. The default route works fine but nothing else does.

These are the routes I have setup:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "HelloRoute",
            "Hello/{name}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Hello" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
```

and on my HomeController I have the corresponding action:

```
    public ActionResult Index ()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC on Mono!";
        return View ();
    }

        public ActionResult Hello(string name)
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "hello "+name;
        return View ();
    }
```

now if I navigate to http://localhost/ I get the message Welcome to...
but if I go to http://localhost/Hello/World I get an error:

```
value name controller does not match any of the values.
```

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.InvalidOperationException: value name controller does not match any of the values.
  at System.Web.Routing.RouteData.GetRequiredString (System.String valueName) [0x00000] 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext) [0x00000] 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext httpContext) [0x00000] 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext httpContext) [0x00000] 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+c__Iterator2.MoveNext () [0x00000] 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000]

am I doing something obviously wrong?

Apart from the aditional route, action and view this is a standard asp.net mvc project created in Monodevelop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this was a bug in the mono routing implementation.

I filled a bug report here: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=500739.
And it has now been fixed, although I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug in the ASP.NET MVC templates for MonoDevelop as suggested in the comments section of this [post](http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2009/04/02/aspnet_mvc_monodevelop_addin_preview).

Comment: Just created an mvc app in visual studio and tried that.
As expected all the default routes worked, but again my custom ones did not.
So I am guessing it is not so much a problem with the mvc templates on mono but the actual routing.

Comment: You must be missing something because I did exactly the same thing in Visual Studio 2008 and both routes worked fine as expected.

Comment: Sorry it worked when I ran it on windows. After moving it to mono+apache it didn't work.